# How to combine 2 rigs in single share with claymore?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, mining-pools, ethminer

I have 2 rigs 6 X RX570. Currently each generating 140 Mhs/s. But if I mine same in both rigs for Ethermine.org pool status showing for only for one rig hashrate (140 Mh/s) not combining both. I would like to see Rig1 + Rig2 hash rate around 280 Mh/s into single pool.

Am I doing wrong?

```
EthDcrMiner64.exe -epool eth-us1.ethermine.org:14444 -ewal MyWalletAddress.tanrigs -epsw x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.tanrigs` may be confusing the pool if it's using your rigs' self-reported hash rate. You should replace that with a unique name for each computer. (I'm assuming that's a worker name provided to the pool; I have no experience in this particular matter). That, or the pool isn't properly determining your hash rate (what happens if you only run one rig?) or your miners are very inefficient at returning shares; the latter can be caused by memory/calculation errors in the GPU, bad network connectivity, or settings leading to stale shares.